# Button Onclick does not work

Tags: java, android, buttonclick

EDIT!
I have this eror if i remove 1 from Oncreate1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYTLv.png

I don't know why my code it doesn't work, I have no errors but nothing happens.

Some help?

here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
    addButtonClickListner();
}

public void addButtonClickListner() {
    Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg) {
        Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not Javascript !

Comment: Are you sure it is javascript?

Comment: First lesson in programming - Know the language you are using!

Comment: It's Java for Android. The use of `Intent` shows that, as does the `Bundle savedInstanceState`.

Comment: @user3570349 Welcome to Stack Overflow. In it's current form, this is unfortunately not a good question. To get a positive response here, edit your question to show what you expect to happen. Also tell us what you have tried to solve it yourself. Also, take a look at the LogCat - you might find clues in there. Good luck!

Comment: sorry guys, i know this is not javascript, the tag came automatically. sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in a method called `onCreate1()`. It's not an activity lifecycle method. Nothing happens because your code is not run. Rename the method to `onCreate()`.

It's a good habit to always add the `@Override` annotation to methods where you intend to override a framework method, such as here. If the annotated method doesn't really override a method, you'll get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
 Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);


    btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg)
        {
            Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
    Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);

    btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg)
        {
            Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure @Override annotation always come with override method (e.g onCreate, onResume,...)
Your method name is a new one "onCreate1" please rename it to "onCreate".
Maybe look like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
    addButtonClickListner();
}

public void addButtonClickListner(){
    Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg) {
        Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,   Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
}
```

Beside that, you should print out some thing every where you want to know how to the app work.

```
Log.d("some text","some text");
```